# Strange Behavior with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I implemented a SnackBar / Toast Message in Swift 4 which allows the developer to set the following display duration (enum) and with the following behaviour:

- .long / .short: Timer gets fired and dismisses the SnackBar **OR the user taps the view and it also dismisses**
- .constant: No Timer, only TapGesture to dismiss

Now in the first case (.long / .short) the SnackBar reacts as expected. Either the Timer fires or the user taps and the view gets dismissed.

**In the second case (.constant) - where there is no timer - the Tap gesture is not recognised and the view doesn't get dismissed**

here are the three functions:

```
    private func defineDismissMode(){
        switch self.message.duration {
        case .short, .long:
            self.setTimer()
        case .constant:
            self.setTapGesture()
        }
    }

    private func setTimer(){
        guard self.timer == nil else {return}
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: self.message.duration.rawValue, target: self, selector: #selector(self.dismissSnackBar), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        self.setTapGesture()
    }

    private func setTapGesture() {
        self.tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissSnackBar))
        self.snackView.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapGestureRecognizer!)
    }

    @objc private func dismissSnackBar(){
      ...
    }
```

Anyone a clue why when `setTapGesture()` is called after `setTimer()` it works and a tap triggers `self.dismissSnackBar` , but when called without `setTimer()` the UITapGestureRecognizer is not triggered?

Note: Yes I checked that `case: .constant -> setTapGesture()` gets called

Comment: Are you doing this on a background thread?

Comment: @agibson007 valid question which I was shortly also looking into, but since setTapGesture() works well when called after setTimer() but not when called directly, I naively figure the thread might have no relevance

Comment: it has relevance. It could be something about adding a timer that forces it to the main thread. I would make sure you are calling from the main thread.

Comment: @agibson007 you could make a point although I might miss the correlation between the two calls in terms of threads. By using .scheduledTimer I indeed set the timer in the main thread; what I miss to understand is why the next call to setTapGesture() would be pulled into the main thread because of the timer (any idea why?). I will thus try - when called without timer - to set the tapgesture into the main thread...

Comment: @agibson007 unfortunately calling it from the main thread hasn't helped